# How can I use cursor positioning in C++

Tags: c++, conio

I am too confused with console screen. I am not able to figure out how to move cursor to random position. This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
   cout<<"Hello World";
   return 0;
}
```

I want to move cursor to random position, not at the beginning after pressing Enter.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. It will never help you.

Comment: You use a third party library. C++ is too low-level to know what a cursor is.

Comment: *I am not able to figure out how to move cursor to random position* -- And neither does standard C++.

Comment: conio.h suggests a Microsoft OS is the target. I believe there is at least one port or off-shoot of [the Curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) targeting Windows

Comment: Try [`gotoxy()`](https://code-reference.com/c/conio.h/gotoxy)?

Comment: That would be the go to, but I don't think it is supported anymore. Prakash, what compiler and version are you using?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to affect the terminal cursor in C++. So, the first step in implementing this is to figure out what system you are targetting, and what API it offers.